# How to know if observed value passed validation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`User 1` has an observer placed on a location.

`User 2` changes something in that particular location, but the data doesn't pass the validation rules. He receives an alert telling him that something went wrong.

The problem is that `User 1` will receive the change `User 2` tried to make, even though it didn't pass the validation stage.

How should `User 1` know if the data he receives is valid?

Comment: User 1 should not receive any updates that fail security rules from another client.

Comment: As Doug said! I suspect you rule might not be effective

Comment: @DougStevenson Hello, Doug. I actually read an article created by you a while ago (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/what-happens-to-database-listeners-when-security-rules-reject-an-update.html) and it seems that the behaviour I am experiencing is expected. I first recieve the updated (and unvalidated) data and immediately after that, I recieve the data before the update (null in my case). So, I guess that I would have to get rid of the Firebase observer and play with threads in my iOS app?

Comment: That article describes what user 1 sees when user 1 makes a change that will eventually be rejected by a security rule.  Any other user on any other device is not involved at all and will not see the change.

Comment: @DougStevenson Only now do I observe that I typed User 2 instead of User 1. I edited my question, sorry.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to show the code that you're using and how you would like to adapt it to address your issue.

Comment: Also, please read again what I said earlier - other users will *never* see updates from another device that fails security rules.  It just can't happen.